# Tayammum instead of gusl

Tags: hadith, sunnah

Assalamu alaikum brother,
I'm having fever now and doctor has suggested not to wash hair while bathing. So can I make gusl without washing hair or should I just do tayammum with soil. Please answer me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wallaikum assalam brother, don't make gusl without washing hair ,just do tayammum with soil.

Please tell me if this answer is helpful for you or not. Assalamualaikum